# Bootstrap 4 navigation from structured folder not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, bootstrap-4

So i have downloaded bootstrap 4 template and using it in my college project in asp.net in visual studio 2010

I have created a master template

```html
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
   <title>EDUCOMP</title>
   <!--Asp PLACEHOLDER HEAD-->
   <!--COPIED STUFF-->

   <!-- Bootstrap core CSS-->
  <link href="~/StyleAsset/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
  <link href="~/StyleAsset/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!-- Page level plugin CSS-->
  <link href="~/StyleAsset/vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
  <link href="~/StyleAsset/css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="~/StyleAsset/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

   <%--<link href="~/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" runat="server"/>
   <link href="~/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" runat="server" />
   <link href="~/css/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" runat="server" />
   <link href="~/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" runat="server" />--%>



   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>

<body class="fixed-nav sticky-footer bg-dark" id="page-top">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav" runat="server">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="Default.aspx">Educatonline</a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
   <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-sidenav" id="exampleAccordion">
      <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Dashboard">
      <asp:HyperLink ID="navlink" runat="server" class="nav-link" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx">
       <i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i>
       <span class="nav-link-text">Dashboard</span>
      </asp:HyperLink>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Instructor">
      <asp:HyperLink ID="dropinstruct" class="nav-link nav-link-collapse collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseComponents" data-parent="#exampleAccordion" runat="server">
       <i class="fa fa-fw fa-wrench"></i>
       <span class="nav-link-text">Instructor</span>
      </asp:HyperLink>
      <ul class="sidenav-second-level collapse" id="collapseComponents">
      <li>
      <asp:HyperLink ID="createcors" NavigateUrl="~/Instructor/create_course.aspx" runat="server">Create Course</asp:HyperLink>
      </li>
      <li>
      <asp:HyperLink ID="addmaterial" NavigateUrl="~/Instructor/addcontent.aspx" runat="server">Add Material</asp:HyperLink>
      </li>
      <li>
      <asp:HyperLink ID="mangcors" NavigateUrl="~/Instructor/manage_course.aspx" runat="server">Manage course</asp:HyperLink>
      </li>
      <li>
      <asp:HyperLink ID="createtest" NavigateUrl="~/Instructor/create_Test.aspx" runat="server">Create Test</asp:HyperLink>
      </li>
      <li>
      <asp:HyperLink ID="managetest" NavigateUrl="~/Instructor/manage_test.aspx" runat="server">Manage Test</asp:HyperLink>
      </li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Student">
      <a class="nav-link nav-link-collapse collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExamplePages" data-parent="#exampleAccordion">
      <i class="fa fa-fw fa-file"></i>
      <span class="nav-link-text">Student</span>
      </a>
      <ul class="sidenav-second-level collapse" id="collapseExamplePages">
      <li>
      <asp:HyperLink ID="enrolled" NavigateUrl="~/Student/View_course.aspx" runat="server">Enrolled Course</asp:HyperLink>
      </li>
      <li>
      <asp:HyperLink ID="testtaken" NavigateUrl="~/Student/test_taken.aspx" runat="server">Test Taken</asp:HyperLink>
      </li>
      </ul>
      </li>

   </ul>
   <ul class="navbar-nav sidenav-toggler">
      <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link text-center" id="sidenavToggler">
      <i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-left"></i>
      </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle mr-lg-2" id="messagesDropdown" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i>
      <span class="d-lg-none">Messages
             
      </span>
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="messagesDropdown">
      <h6 class="dropdown-header">New Messages:</h6>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle mr-lg-2" id="alertsDropdown" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <i class="fa fa-fw fa-bell"></i>
      <span class="d-lg-none">Alerts
             
      </span>
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="alertsDropdown">
      <h6 class="dropdown-header">New Alerts:</h6>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
      <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
   </div>
   </nav>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <!--script manager-->
   <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
   <!-- Navigation-->
   
   <!--MAIN CONTENT START-->
   <div class="content-wrapper">
   <div class="container-fluid">
   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
   </div>
   <!-- /.container-fluid-->
   </div>
   <!-- /.content-wrapper-->

   <!--FOOTER-->

   <footer class="sticky-footer">
   <div class="container">
   <div class="text-center">
      <small>Copyright © Your Website 2018</small>
   </div>
   </div>
   </footer>
   <!-- Scroll to Top Button-->
   <a class="scroll-to-top rounded" href="#page-top">
   <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
   </a>
   <!-- Logout Modal-->
   <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
   <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Ready to Leave?</h5>
      <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
      </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">Select "Logout" below if you are ready to end your current session.</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      <asp:Button ID="cancelmodel" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
      <asp:Button ID="logoutmodal" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Logout" OnClick="logoutmodal_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="False" data-dismiss="modal" />
      </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </asp:Panel>


   </form>


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
    <script src="StyleAsset/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="StyleAsset/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
    <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Page level plugin JavaScript-->
    <script src="vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
    <script src="js/sb-admin.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom scripts for this page-->
    <script src="js/sb-admin-datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/sb-admin-charts.min.js"></script>





    <%--<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/umd/popper.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--%>

    <%--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>--%>
</body>
</html>
```

my project have folder structure like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKKJf.png)

but when i navigate to this page below or any similar page which is within a folder

```
<li><asp:HyperLink ID="createcors" NavigateUrl="~/Instructor/create_course.aspx" runat="server">Create Course</asp:HyperLink></li>
```

the navigation doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load javascript within Master page using Page.ResolveURL because at individual page level the path won't properly figure out js files

So for example like this

```
<script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.js") %>"></script>
<script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js") %>"></script>
```

You can change the path with your file path

Hope it helps